# PREG REPLACE ERROR ALPHA NUMERIC STRING - MYSQL

Tags: mysql, preg-replace

Hi  I used the preg_replace for replace the non alpha numeric data with ''.

1)

```
SELECT 
    PREG_REPLACE('[^A-Za-z0-9]','',CATALOGUEREFERENCE) AS INSTRUMENT
FROM
    FILES;
```

2)

```
select 
    preg_replace('[[:alnum:]]', '',CATALOGUEREFERENCE) as instrument
from
    files;
```

First query displays the  records as blob and the second query displays null records. Can anyone suggest the query modification for replacing the non alpha numeric data with ''.

**Input file** : 
GETA2000003890
MAC00007000
NAS00006000
MAS000007000
MAS2SA200006000

**Desired output**:
GET 
MAC
NAS
MAS
MAS2SA2

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think your desired output is: **GET MAC NAS MAS MAS**.

Code:

```
$input = 'GETA2000003890 MAC00007000 NAS00006000 MAS000007000 MAS2SA200006000';
$output = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{3})(\w*)/i', '$1', $input);
echo $output; // GET MAC NAS MAS MAS
```